# How to cut lines to clipboard in vim? not yanking or copying but cutting

Tags: vim

I used to `"+y` or `"*y` to yank lines to clipboard to paste it in other files. Often I need to move the lines from file to file, in other words, cut and paste between files. However, selecting the lines to be moved, copying them them to clipboard, and then re-selecting the same lines and deleting them, before pasting them in another file is quite cumbersome.

Is there any way to achieve this more easily? For an instance, selecting lines to be moved -> `"+d` from source file -> `"+p` to destination file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deletion commands such as `d`, `c` and `x` also yank the deleted contents. Hence `dd` does not simply deletes the current line, it cuts it. Same for `dap`, `dG`, `c$` and so on.

Comment: it deletes lines and can be pasted elsewhere in the same file though, it can't be pasted to another file like `"+y` -> `"+p`. or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3 you can specify the “register” (clipboard) just as with `y`: for instance `"+dd` for cutting the current line into the X graphical clipboard. Also, if you want Vim’s copy-pasting to be better integrated with the outside world, you may `:set clipboard=unnamedplus` so that commands use the register `"+` i.e. the graphical clipboard by default.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu without X server, which is EC2 server. is this the cause? I can only copy-n-paste with "+y and "+p between files. Unfortunately "+d and "+p works only in the same file :( ...

Comment: (Apologies, a more correct command would be `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus`.)

Comment: Yes, `"+` would only work within a graphical env. I’m not sure which environments are supported beyond X11 (see `:help registers` and `:help quoteplus` perhaps) *but* I’m surprised that `"+y` would work if `"+d` wouldn’t. They use the exact same feature. Do you open both files in the same instance of Vim? In any case, Vim’s internal registers, including the default “unnamed” register (`""`), are not local to a file/buffer, but to an *instance of Vim*. So you can copy-paste from file A to file B if you have opened A and B in the same instance of Vim, whichever register you use.

Comment: I think it was my fault.. I couldn't reproduce the same thing ("+y -> "+p between different files). So I gotta find another way.. `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus` and `"+` and `"*` didn't work

Comment: ~I solved it by exporting `export DISPLAY=:0.0` :D~ nevermind.. I thought I solved it.. but it wasn't..

Comment: I really really have solved it by installing xvfb for emulating X server clipboard and export DISPLAY=:0.0 and now I'm happy to move lines across files